# Transfer ether from one account to another using smart contract

Tags: solidity, ether, address.transfer, nethereum

I`m trying to transfer ether from account A to a smart contract and from the smart contract to account B. I wrote some code that approximately works on Remix IDE, but I completely got lost with the msg.value.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
contract MyFirstContract
{
    function() external payable { }
        function getBalance() public view returns(uint)
        {
            return address(this).balance;
        }
        
    function send(address payable _To )public payable returns (bool)
    {
     _To.transfer(msg.value);
     return true;
    }
}
```

This works fine if I insert an input in the value textbox on Remix, as shown in the next image:
[image]

### Remix IDE value

But I need to transfer ether using my Dapp which based on C#. So, how am I supposed to set the msg.value there? Can I do it using Solidity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution in C# (Nethereum):

```
        var contractABI = @"[{""constant"":true,""inputs"":[],""name"":""getBalance"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":"""",""type"":""uint256""}],""payable"":false,""stateMutability"":""view"",""type"":""function""},{""constant"":false,""inputs"":[{""internalType"":""address payable"",""name"":""_to"",""type"":""address""},{""internalType"":""uint256"",""name"":""_value"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""send"",""outputs"":[{""internalType"":""bool"",""name"":"""",""type"":""bool""}],""payable"":false,""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},{""payable"":true,""stateMutability"":""payable"",""type"":""fallback""}]";
        var senderAddressTest = myAccount.AccountAddress;
        var recipientAddressTest = "0x7988dfD8E9ceCb888C1AeA7Cb416D44C6160Ef80";
        var senderPrivateKeyTest = myAccount.AccountPassword;
        var accountTest = new Nethereum.Web3.Accounts.Account(senderPrivateKeyTest);
        var web3Test = new Web3(accountTest, myAccount.AccountNetwork + "" + myAccount.InfuraApiKey); var contractByteCode = "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";
        var receiptContract = await web3Test.Eth.DeployContract.SendRequestAndWaitForReceiptAsync(contractABI, contractByteCode, senderAddressTest, new HexBigInteger(900000), null);
        var contractAddress2 = receiptContract.ContractAddress;
        var contractTest2 = web3Test.Eth.GetContract(contractABI, contractAddress2);
        var transaction2 = await web3Test.Eth.GetEtherTransferService().TransferEtherAndWaitForReceiptAsync(contractAddress2, 1.00m, 2, new BigInteger(25000));
        var wieEtherTest2 = 1000000000000000000; // = 1 ETH
        var getBalanceFunction2 = contractTest2.GetFunction("getBalance");
        var resultGetBalance2 = await getBalanceFunction2.CallAsync<UInt64>(); // work
        var sendFunction2 = contractTest2.GetFunction("send");
        var gas2 = await sendFunction2.EstimateGasAsync(senderAddressTest, null, null, recipientAddressTest, wieEtherTest2);
        var receiptAmountSend2 = await sendFunction2.SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync(senderAddressTest, gas2, null, null, recipientAddressTest, wieEtherTest2);
```

Comment: In this code first I deployed the contract, and then send it the ether. Later I use the 'send' method to send ether to another account from the contract`s balance

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Solidity. That is solely the language to write smart contracts in. You have (at least) 2 options:

### web3.js

If your C# dApp has a browser based frontend you can use the library web3.js. A possible call in your JavaScript code would look something like this:

```
const receiverAddress=""xxx;
await MyFirstContract.methods.send(reveiverAddress).send({ from: account, value: amountToSendWei });
```

`amountToSendWei` is the amount you wanna transfer. The function name "send" might create issues because it is already used within web3.

### Nethereum

An open source .NET integration library for Ethereum. I don't have personal experience with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did u got the answer i have been trying since to weeks
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
contract MyFirstContract
{
function() external payable { }
function getBalance() public view returns(uint)
{
return address(this).balance;
}

```
function send(address payable _To )public payable returns (bool)
{
 _To.transfer(msg.value);
 return true;
}
```

}

i dont want to use value button

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/71953)